# jquery and hiding labels

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form which has a set of fields which I would like hidden on initial page load, I have done this using jquery) which works however in Internet Explorer the padding and height of these hidden fields is still visible so I'm left with huge spacing everywhere.

Any idea how I can get jquery to hide this padding? Thanks

Comment: It might be easiest to render the page with `display: none` in the style attributes and then just use jQuery to display them as required.

Comment: it's best to accept some answers before asking new questions :)

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the fields in a `div` and hide the div on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't alter the layout, try wrapping the content you want to hide in a new DIV using jquery's [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) and then hide the new DIV.

```
    $('#ExistingElement').wrap('<div class="newDivToHideStuff" />');
    $('.newDivToHideStuff').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

whatever you want to hide, you could wrap it in a div and hide that whole div altogether, no ?

Answer (score 0):

If the element is hidden, so will its `padding` and `height`.

This is unless you are using `visibility: hidden`. Don't do that - use `hide()` (which is `display: none`).

Comment: I am using hide :( Basically I can't hide all of the fields because they want one shown, it's code which is pulled in from another site so I can't alter how it is laid out.